# how to escape single and double quotes in mysql backup(.sql file) that is taken using mysqldump

Tags: php, mysql

I want to take daily backup of my DB for that I use following code

```
$username =escapeshellcmd($dbuser);
$password =escapeshellcmd($dbpwd);
$hostname =escapeshellcmd($server);
$database =escapeshellcmd($dbname);

$backupFile='/mypath/dbBackup/'.date("Y-m-d-H-i-s").'.sql';
$command = "mysqldump -u$username -p$password -h$hostname $database > $backupFile";
system($command, $result);
```

I place this code in php file and call that file through cron job that I set to take daily DB backup. This works fine but problem is my column in table contains content that have number of single and double quotes. Because of this when backup file is created (.SQL file) it contains broken INSERT query like this

```
INSERT INTO `mytable` VALUES (1,'don\'t read this article','test\'ssdf','',1,5,6,0),(2,'goal setting tips you\'d want to try','Category- ' ....
```

So is there any way to escape these single and double quotes in .SQL backup file while using mysqldump.

Comment: That query doesn't look broken to me...

Comment: Au contraire, the backslashes **unbreak** the query. They *are* escaping the quotes.

Comment: Alternatively use `mysqldump --xml` if the SQL syntax confuses you. (This comment is meant for bemusement. Not an actual advise.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't have to escape anything in the MySQL backup file.

Comment: Thanks for reply but when I take manual backup using phpmyadmin->Export the backup contains double single quotes means where single quote is present extra single quote is added. Why this added. I m confused.

Comment: there are several ways of quoting. you may quote a single quote with either backslash or the same quote. why phpmyadmin prefer one method over another I don't know. but anyway it doesn't matter too much